# Sitefinity 11 Ecomerce Widget is not displaying in right section of page content

Tags: telerik, sitefinity, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-8, sitefinity-feather

I just installed trial version of Sitefinity 11. Now I was trying to use ProductList widget, but on editing page content I got no option for Ecommerce Menu in right panel. Please see the below image:

[image]

I wonder why this happened. I have checked the settings section also, see the below image:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have also checked Administration -> ModulesAndServices section, the Ecommerce module is already active, please see the below image:
[image]

Edit2: I was reading sitifinity document & came to following text provided at [this link](https://docs.sitefinity.com/overview-setup-the-ecommerce-pages):

```
IMPORTANT: For all of your ecommerce pages, you must turn off caching. You must install SSL certificate on the website and you must configure your login, checkout, and any confirmation pages to require SSL.
```

**It does sound like page should be https to use Ecommerce widget**, is this so as I tried to create https page but could not edit it as my SSL certificate was invalid as per Sitefinity.

**EDIT3: I have installed self signed Certificate & successfully logged into Sitefinity admin, but still I didn't got the Ecommerce option in right panel.** See the below image for options i used to create page:
[image]

Any body has any idea for solving this problem will be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Activate the eCommerce module - go to Administration > Modules and Services and activate it.

Edit: eCommerce widgets are only available in Hybrid or WebForms page templates. 
If your page template is pure MVC (MVC-only) then you won't be able to see the ecommerce widgets.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how do we identify which template is used?

Comment: I got it, when we select template for page then it's displaying mvc in bottom right.

Comment: or you can check in the DB - sf_page_templates table, framework field.
Corresponds to PageTemplateFramework enum:

    public enum PageTemplateFramework
    {
        Hybrid,
        Mvc,
        WebForms
    }